# Is there a term for a word of one meaning but variable pronunciation?

Tags: terminology

For example, "advertisement", and "component".

edit: Here's the full list that I have compiled that I had in mind:
advertisement
Arkansas
asterisk
athelete
auxiliary
Berkeley
builded
component
coupon
data
either
employee
February
forte
kilometer
library
Lima
mature
medieval
meme
miniature
mischievous
neither
niche
nuclear
often
ornery
pecan
probably
ribald
route
sherbet
temperature
temperament
Tijuana
vegetable
vehicle
verbiage
zoological
zoologist

Comment: The tone of your question implies that you're well aware that two words that have the same spelling but different pronunciations associated with different meanings are called ***heteronyms***.

Answer (score 2):

Practically ***every*** word in English has variable pronunciation, depending on who's speaking to whom, and where, when, how, and why they're doing so. Variation in pronunciation is a fact of language; otherwise we wouldn't be able to recognize individual people's voices.

Of the words you offer for example, *advertisement* has variant stress patterns (NB -- all pronounceable *ad lib* with either syllabic resonants or epenthetic /ər, əm/ & /ən/ -- /'æd.vr.tayz.mnt/ vs /æd.vr.'tayz.mnt/) which I associate with American and British English, respectively; and I know of no pronunciation variants for *component*, which is /km.'po.nnt/ with stress on the second syllable's tense /o/ in my American English, but may well be pronounced differently elsewhere. I don't know. I'm not a dialectologist; I'm a semanticist.

So it's not at all clear what you're asking for. We don't spend all our time sitting around thinking up one-word names for every possible situation, you know. Who cares? Names are just names, and then only when somebody else uses them; like phone numbers, they mean nothing in themselves.